# Kotlin Interface can't be instantiated! Interface name: kotlinx.coroutines.Deferred

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-coroutines

Im working on an Android App that is using MVVM with Koin and Retrofit.

Suddenly i keep receiving an error saying

> Interface can't be instantiated! Interface name:
>   kotlinx.coroutines.Deferred

however i cannot find where's the problem.

The current structure is this.

ViewModel.

```
class ExchangeRateBanksViewModel (private val comercialBanksRepository: ComercialBanksRepository): ViewModel() , KoinComponent{

    private val _uiState = MutableLiveData<CredentialsDataState>()
    val uiState: LiveData<CredentialsDataState> get() = _uiState

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            runCatching {
                emitUiState(showProgress = true)
                comercialBanksRepository.getExchangeRateByToday()
            }.onSuccess {root ->
                val nameMap: MutableList<ExchangeRate> = root.data.map { it }.toMutableList()
                emitUiState(result = Event(nameMap))
            }.onFailure {
                println(it.printStackTrace())
            }
        }
    }

    private fun emitUiState(showProgress: Boolean = false, result: Event<List<ExchangeRate>>? = null, error: Event<Int>? = null){
        val dataState = CredentialsDataState(showProgress, result, error)
        _uiState.value = dataState
    }

    data class CredentialsDataState(val showProgress: Boolean, val result: Event<List<ExchangeRate>>?, val error: Event<Int>?)
}
```

the interface

```
interface ComercialBanksInterface {
    @GET("api/commercialBankExchangeRates/date/today")
    suspend fun requestExchangeRateToday(): Deferred<RootExchangeRate>
}
```

the repository.

```
interface ComercialBanksRepository {
    suspend fun getExchangeRateByToday(): RootExchangeRate
}

class ComercialBanksRepositoryImplement(val comercialBanksService: ComercialBanksInterface): ComercialBanksRepository{
    override suspend fun getExchangeRateByToday(): RootExchangeRate {
        return comercialBanksService.requestExchangeRateToday().await()
    }
}
```

and finally the section where i call my viewModel.

```
exchangeRateBanksViewModel.uiState.observe(this, Observer {
            val dataState = it ?: return@Observer
            if (!dataState.showProgress) displayHideSkeleton(hide = true) else displayHideSkeleton(hide = false)
            if (dataState.result != null && !dataState.result.consumed){
                dataState.result.consume()?.let { result ->
                    println("RESULT: ${result}")
                    exchangeRateAdapter.submitList(result)
                }
            }
            if (dataState.error != null && !dataState.error.consumed){
                dataState.error.consume()?.let { error ->
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, resources.getString(error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        })
```

I can't find which part the interface has the problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Retrofit already handles suspend functions so you don't need to return `Deferred`. Just return `RootExchangeRate` and that's it.

Also your repository's function should also be suspendable, and the view model should return a LiveData, where the activity (or fragment) will observe it.

Comment: problem solved. You were right... i didn't know that retrofit already handle the awaits jajaja. I remove that section of the code and now it works. Thanks good sir.

Comment: No worries mate. Glad I've been able to help